# Importing AppKit.h: function does not return NSString

Tags: objective-c, clang, neovim, coc.nvim

I am using Nvim to try and develop a Mac application. I have just imported AppKit.h to instantiate a `sharedApplication`.

I am using `coc-clangd` for autocompletion. I am getting the following error when I import AppKit.h.

```
In included file: function does not return NSString
[clang: format_attribute_result_not]
```

[image]

The code:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <AppKit/AppKit.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  printf("Hello world");
  return 0;
}
```

I should also mention that the code is compiling just fine. I have tried the following compile commands and both of them have worked.

```
clang -framework AppKit -o a osx_main.mm
```

```
clang -Wall -o a osx_main.mm
```

Comment: Do you employ any linter here and if not, could you include the compile command?

Comment: @TheDreamsWind I think `coc` handles the linting. I have edited the question to include the compile command.

Answer (score 1):

You should choose command line tool version,
Xcode ▶ Preferences ▶ Location ▶ Command Line Tool ▶
then choose appropriate command line tool version.